# What means T there <T>($winstonLoggerConfig<T>) => $winstonLogger<T> in winston v3?

Tags: javascript, node.js, flowtype, winston, flow-typed

I'm using winston logger and wnat to flow type it. But I don't know what should I pass to .
My logger:

```
const logger = createLogger({
...
});

Missing type annotation for `T`. `T` is a type parameter declared in function type [1] and was implicitly instantiated
at call of `createLogger` [2].

...

   startup/logger.js:35:16
                      v-------------
   35| const logger = createLogger({

References:
   flow-typed/npm/winston_v3.x.x.js:98:19
   98|     createLogger: <T>($winstonLoggerConfig<T>) => $winstonLogger<T>,
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ [1]
```

Also i found this in flow-typed library:

```
declare type $winstonLoggerConfig<T: $winstonLevels> = {
  exitOnError?: boolean,
  format?: $winstonFormat,
  level?: $Keys<T>,
  levels?: T,
  transports?: Array<$winstonTransport>
};

declare type $winstonLogger<T: $winstonLevels> = {
  [$Keys<T>]: (message: string, meta?: Object) => void,
  add: $winstonTransport => void,
  clear: () => void,
  configure: ($winstonLoggerConfig<T>) => void,
  log: (message: $winstonInfo<T>) => void,
  remove: $winstonTransport => void
};
```

So what should I pass to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know where the error comes from, but I can explain what the `T` is.

The `T` here is a [generic type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/). This is useful when you want to constrain the types but not too much. For example imagine you have a `Bag` type:

```
type Bag = {
    name: string,
    content: Array<number>
}
```

You may find too restrictive to only put numbers in your bags, lets say you want to have strings in some bags and numbers in some others, you would then change your types to:

```
type NumberBag = {
    name: string,
    content: Array<number>
}
type StringBag = {
    name: string,
    content: Array<string>
}
```

But a better way to do this is to only have constraints on what you want, here the real constraint we want is "a bag only contains a single kind of things" (`string` or `number`). This is where generic types are useful:

```
type Bag<GenericType> = {
    name: string,
    content: Array<GenericType>
}
```

Now you may want to be a bit more specific, imagine you only want bags to contain either numbers or string (as we did before):

```
type Bag<GenericType: number | string> = {
    name: string,
    content: Array<GenericType>
}
```

Ok, now imagine that you want to declare a new bag:

```
const firstBag: Bag = {
    name: "Integer bag", 
    content: [1,3,4]
};
```

If you only do that you'll have a (flow) error saying:

> ```
> Cannot use `Bag` [1] without 1 type argument.
> 1: type Bag<GenericType: number | string> =
> ```

The type argument this is referring to is the generic type (that defines what will be in the bag).

In other words this means, there are no "**Bag**s" there are "**Bag**s of things" and that "thing" needs to be defined. Therefore, when creating a Bag you need to specify the exact Bag type that you want to use:

```
const firstBag: Bag<number> = {
    name: "Integer bag", 
    content: [1,3,4]
};
```

This works the same for functions and classes, they both can be parametrized by a generic type.

In your case you it seems like you have a function `createLogger` with a generic type attached to it. This generic type is also constrained to be `$winstonLevels` (thats the equivalent of the `number | string` we had for bags). But I think that not specifying the type here shouldn't be a type error, do you have the declaration of the function `createLogger`?

The code for the toy example is [here](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAQghgcwDwHEIDsICcCWBjAFXAgC4p0BXAWwCNsoAfKAZ2F3QQD4oBeKAbwBQUcnCqkWbHBwA0wqHgD26YBmBkAglixwQqDNnxFInQQF9BggGYV0eYDmVQ4AExcBJVVSQEylWvRMrOxcABQ0iGTwyAScMlA4XiQEAJRRiD6cQgCQWBDAFFjoAvLZ2ehiEhEIAHQV4nIiZUoqamQA2jVd1TUtqirxiRBUALpQgtlmANzmli2sUFY4WKzR6cj+dFjcfEIiIvUSAETurQj01UfxE31tUO0AjDIAzDIALCPmM4LzwCwQLRc0V4zjcnmGoSWK2A0XiAHYUt9BAB6ZFQAgACxwzCgVF0UAANopFABrQk4EnQECKQqLWz2RzoEjWekOJx4PJwVQAUSoYFA0R8fmoW0YkhCnFChxIwWkCDSsAysRyeQKRQEogaCmU-XU9xG01mP2UC2AWKwQMiiuQso4OwUnJ5fIFiFCRw06EUZvo0lU5ywUEuiKAA).

---

Edit: what version of flow are you using by the way?

Comment: Sorry for that, I already fix it, but I like your answer. Thank you for an explanation to me about generic types in simple way

Answer (score 3):

The flowtype config is looking for the log level mapping to be passed in here.  Winston provides one out of the box: `NpmLogLevels`.

You can use it like so:

```
import { createLogger, type NpmLogLevels } from 'winston';

const logger = createLogger<NpmLogLevels>({
  transports: [new transports.Console()],
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this nice, simple answer. It directly resolved a type error I was having - sometimes the error output is hard to parse into a fix.